# DATEDIFF on Dates in Multiple Rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, datetime, datediff

I'm trying to find the number of days between the initial visit and the return visit for customers in a restaurant, but I'm having some trouble doing so since the dates of the initial visit and the return visit are on separate rows. The data is sensitive, so I can't post it here, but it looks something like this:

[image: Picture of Data]

If DATEDIFF isn't the best choice here, can someone suggest another function?

Comment: At least take the time to post your data in an easy to copy format.

Comment: What SQL server version are you using?

Comment: Apologies Salman, I was in a rush, and all the text tables I tried to post came out jumbled. Also, I'm using SQL Server 17.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can summarize the data using `group by` . . . assuming one row of each type per customer (which is consistent with your sample data):

```
select customer_id, min(initial_visit), max(return_visit)
from t
group by customer_id;
```

Then you can calculate the difference.  That depends on the database.  Some support a special function.  Some just use `-`.  You should consult the documentation for the database you are using.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I'm not sure if this works with Customer_ID 2, though, since it misses the first return visit. If I'm trying to find all customers who returned within, say, 20 days, I would think this method would miss customer 2 since the difference would be 3/15 - 2/15.

Comment: @GhostBen . . . What you specify in your comment is not in the question.  This answers the question *you asked*.  I would suggest that you ask *another* question, with more appropriate sample data, desired results, and a good explanation of what you are trying to accomplish.